# "non-read-only mapping defined for the primary key field"

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa, oracle11g, eclipselink

And I created entities from `tableA`, `tableB`, `tableC` from my database.

`tableA` has foreign key to `tableB` and has unidirectional Many-to-One relationship. `tableC` has two primary keys and one of these is foreign key to primary key in `tableA`. `tableC` also has unidirection Many-to-One relationship to `tableA`.

Then I created session bean and data control from it, in design window, created read-only table from `tableA`.

And I selected columns in `tableA` and also in `tableB`.

I ran the application and saw the following exception in log window.

> Local Exception Stack:
>   Exception [EclipseLink-46] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.1.3.v20110304-r9073): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException
>   Exception Description: There should be one non-read-only mapping defined for the primary key field [tableC.tableA_ID].
>   Descriptor: RelationalDescriptor(mypack.tableC --> [DatabaseTable(tableC)])

`tableA_ID` is a primary key in `tableA`.

How can I solve this error?

Answer (score 4):

Please post the code for your `@Entity` classes.

My best guess, though, is that you have the tableA_ID column on tableC in two separate mappings, once as part of a `@ManyToOne` and again as a field (perhaps as part of an `@EmbeddedId`).  JPA only lets you manage the underlying column through a single writeable mapping.

If you want both mappings, *you have to pick which one you'll use to write*, and designate the other as read-only with `insertable=false, updatable=false`.

For example:

```
@Entity
pubilc class TableC {

  // read-write mapping to manage via relationship 
  @ManyToOne(column="tableA_ID")
  private TableA tableA;

  // read-only convenience method to get ID directly w/o navigating relationship
  @Column(name="tableA_ID", insertable=false, updatable=false)
  private Long tableA_ID;
}
```

Comment: see above - you have to pick which one you'll use to write

Answer (score 0):

[pedant]I suppose that by "tableC has two primary keys" you mean "tableC has a primary key made of two columns".[/pedant]

"Then I created session bean and data control from it, in design window, created read-only table from tableA."

Does that mean that you marked the bean mapped for tableA as globally read-only? If so, depending on the mapping, you may encounter the same as [here](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/671130/) where EclipeLink concludes that it's not possible to create a new entity since it depends on a read-only entity.

Comment: tableC has a primary key made of two columns.
In Oracle JDeveloper, I dragged tableAFindAll from SessionEJB into the jspx file. I have also pk class of tableC.
Thanks.